# How to create a subset with a given length and mean?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems, python

I have a set of numbers $P=\{p_1,\dotsc,p_{|P|}\}$, where $|P|$ is the length of the set. I want to select a subset, $S$, from $P$ such that its mean is approximately equal to a predefined value $\mu_s$ .

$$\sum_{x \in S} x \approx \mu_s * |S|$$
My problem:

- $|P|$ = 5000
- $|S|$ = 1500
- $\mu_s$ $\approx$ 90 $(target$ $mean)$
- $\mu_p$ = 95
- $min(P)$ = 0
- $max(P)$ = 300

I am looking for algorithm suggestions so I can implement this in Python. I would also like $S$ to include a range of values, rather than just the naive approach of sorting from smallest to largest first, then applying a greedy algorithm.

Additional question is whether dynamic programming could be used for this type of problem (i.e. we have to select a certain number of items from a list such that the sum is as close as possible to the capacity limit)?

Comment: 1. By "length" do you mean "size"? 2. "I would like $S$ to include a range of values" isn't a criterion that can be incorporated in an algorithm.

Comment: (If you don't like a particular solution, one approach is to remove some/all of the chosen elements from $P$ and rerun.)

Comment: Since $|S|$ is specified as the input, this is simply the ordinary Subset Sum problem (or equivalently, Knapsack with all values equal to 1) with target weight $|S|\mu_s$.

Comment: What does the notation $\mu_p$ represent?

Comment: Hi @j_random_hacker, yes by length I mean size. I agree, the way I am currently trying to solve it is by treating it as a knapsack problem where all values are equal to 1 and with the addition requirement that I use 1500 numbers exactly.

Comment: Hi @D.W, this is the mean of the set P. It actually isn't important for my particular problem, but I included it in case the question was asked

Answer (score 1):

For every $i \in \{0,\ldots,|P|\}$, $j \in \{0,\ldots,|S|\}$, and $T \in \{0,\ldots,\mathcal{T}\}$ (I discuss $\mathcal{T}$ below), compute whether there is a subset of size $j$ of $p_1,\ldots,p_i$ which sums to $T$. You should take $\mathcal{T}$ to be your maximum allowable answer – $\max(P) \cdot |S|$ would definitely do, but you can probably pick something which is closer to $\mu_S |S|$, say $\mu_P |S|$. The running time is $O(|P| |S| \mathcal{T})$. In your case, assuming you choose $\mathcal{T} \approx \mu_p |S|$, then $|P| |S| \mathcal{T} \approx 2^{40}$, so this is barely feasible.

This is a naive dynamic programming algorithm, which probably can be improved, especially since you're only looking for an approximation.

For example, you could only look for solutions such that $S \cap \{0,\ldots,i\} \approx \frac{|S|}{|P|} i$ and $\sum(S \cap \{0,\ldots,i\}) \approx \frac{|S|}{|P|} \mu_S$, which will reduce the running time significantly. While this is only a heuristic, it might be possible to show that you get a decent approximation on average, if you randomize the order of $P$.

Another possible optimization is to quantize the partial sums, quantizing more aggressively as $i$ gets larger. If done carefully, you won't lose much in accuracy but will have a significant gain in running time.

Comment: Thanks @Yuval for your help, I will take a look at your suggestions. My current approach uses dynamic programming where I also include a condition that the subset be a certain size (all values are the same). It works, but it can be improved